# ImmmutalbeJS: filtering a List of Maps

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Let's say I have a `List` of items of `Map` type.
I want to filter the list.
According to the documentation I would do something like that:

```
people.filter(person =>
  person.get('name') === 'David' &&
  person.get('lastName') === 'Smith');
```

I'd rather achieve the same by writing something less verbose:

```
people.filter({ name: 'David', lastName: 'Smith' });
```

(LoDash style)

Is there such a way? Anything more elegant than the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let fullNameList = Immutable.List([{name: 'David', lastName: 'Smith'}, {name: 'David', lastName: 'King'}, {name: 'Some', lastName: 'Dude'}]);

let firstName = Immutable.Map({name: 'David'});

let result = fullNameList.filter(fullName=>firstName.isSubset(fullName));
```